# Secure Boot Violation on samsung

Tags: 14.04, boot, samsung

I need help! I just install 14.04 in my Samsung but when I press the reboot option I get the following message:

Secure Boot Violation
Invalid signature detected. If this error persists, seek technical assistance

I don't know what to do, but need my laptop for work. Can you give me some tips? I appreciate your time, I know your are busy!

Have a good day, Armando﻿

Answer (score 4):

Go into BIOS by clicking F2 right as you start up the computer. Go in and find "boot." Find secure boot, then turn it off. Viola.

Comment: Hi Viola, thanks for the answer! Let me try and I will let you know what happens

Comment: This help me on my ASUS laptop as well! Many thanks!

Comment: @Armando Viola means "It is done!". Not my name...